# Pl/sql query to display results for 900+ records using loop

Tags: sql, oracle

[Here's the query that I've made for only 1 data(site_serial_number)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKaFL.jpg)

I need to find all the 900+ rows. How to proceed from here? How to make this query for single row run in a loop for the rest of the records. Total rows are 957.

Below is the table given in picture, I want to find if the eam_group =transformer is present in site_serial_number.thus I've made the query for the 1st row.

```
Select B.* 
From xxeam_mr_assets A, xxeam_mr_assets B
Where A.Eamid ='SITE-00266799' and A.end_date is null and 
B. Eam_group='TRANSFORMER' and B.end_date is null and SDO_RELATE(A.MR_GEOM, B.MR_GEOM, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') ='True';
```

Need this Where clause for 900 records". Eg there are 900 SITES

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a PL/SQL or loops, just `JOIN` the tables:

```sql
SELECT b.*
FROM   XXEAM.XXEAM_WACS_Child_RM_transl@APPS_SP_TO_EAM w
       INNER JOIN xxeam_mr_assets A
       ON a.Eamid = w.site_serial_number
       INNER JOIN xxeam_mr_assets B
       ON SDO_RELATE(A.MR_GEOM, B.MR_GEOM, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') ='True'
WHERE  a.end_date is null
AND    b. Eam_group='TRANSFORMER'
AND    b.end_date is null;
```

Comment: What should be my next course of action from here if I want to insert the values in other transformer spid and other transformer eamid. Note: I'm trying to find if any other eam_group is present in site_serial number value. If present, we will add the spid and eam id of the sites in last two columns. And also add a remark column if more than one transformer is present in site.